# how to send a collection/array to mvc action via ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

atm I'm trying like this, but no luck, I get null in my Do action

```
var arr = [31,17,16];

$.get('<%=Url.Action("Do", "Foo") %>', 
       {ids:arr},
       function(d){...});

public ActionResult Do(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the values are being sent? Use your browser's developer tools to check the request headers

Comment: @Bloodsplatter it calls this http://localhost/awe/Foo/Do?ids%5B%5D=31&ids%5B%5D=17&ids%5B%5D=16

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%= Url.Action("Do", "Foo") %>',
    data: { ids: [ 31, 17, 16] },
    traditional: true,
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

Notice the [`traditional: true`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) parameter.

Or if you insist on the `$.get()` function:

```
$.get(
    '<%= Url.Action("Do", "Foo") %>', 
    $.param({ ids: [31, 17, 16] }, true), 
    function (result) {

    }
);
```

Comment: @hunter that's without traditional ?

Comment: @Omu, traditional is another parameter, it is not part of the data hash.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this problem, but found an alternative solution instead.  I prefer this over `traditional`, so I'll post it here so others can choose for themselves.

```
$.ajax(url, 
    {
        type: method,                    //"GET", or "POST", etc. The REST verb
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),    //stringify your collection or complex object
        contentType:"application/json",  //tell the controller what to expect
        complete: callback
    });
});
```

This works for every data type I've sent, no matter how complex.  We actually have this wrapped in a class called `RequestService` which does this for all requests from our client script to the MVC API Controller. There are plenty of other nice attributes to give this object, like `timeout`, or `headers`. Check out the full docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

I'm running .NET Framework 4.5, and JQuery 1.7.1, though I believe this version of `$.ajax` is since 1.5

Comment: do you have to deserialize the myData manually at the server side or the Default ModelBinder does that automatically

Comment: @ChuckNorris As long as you specify the contentType when using stringify, the framework takes care of the deserializing for you.