# Passing JS array to MVC controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

In my page I have some inputs for users to input values, then I shall get all the values and send them to server. Now I can get the value and I display them just like below:

```
Cylinder: 0.00    Sphere: 0.00    Quantity:1
Cylinder: -0.25    Sphere: 0.00    Quantity:2
Cylinder: -0.50    Sphere: 0.00    Quantity:33
Cylinder: -0.75    Sphere: 0.00    Quantity:2
Cylinder: -1.00    Sphere: 0.00    Quantity:2
Cylinder: -1.25    Sphere: 0.00    Quantity:33
Cylinder: -1.50    Sphere: 0.00    Quantity:4
Cylinder: -1.75    Sphere: 0.00    Quantity:5
Cylinder: -2.00    Sphere: 0.00    Quantity:4
```

But i dont know how to send them to action for saving. I'm using mvc.

In the view I write the following JavaScript:

```
 var orderModel={};
 $(".bulkOrderNumericInput").each(function (index,element) {
        if ($(this).val().length!=0) {
            orderModel[i]={Cylinder:$(this).attr('valuex'),Sphere:$(this).attr('valuey'),Quantity:$(this).val()};
            i++;
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I take it you're using jQuery. Are you wanting to see how to use AJAX to send a JavaScript array to the server? I can't see any MVC - is this the generic design pattern, or do you mean the .net technology?

Comment: Thanks guys all above. You are so kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var orderModel = [];
//loop all the inputs in the page to get values, let's say you give all the inputs a class named'.orderinput'
$('#checkout').click(function(){
    $(".orderinput").each(function(){
    orderModel.push({Cylinder:$(this).val(),Sphere:blah,Quantity:blah,...);
    });
  });

//not all values are sotred into the orderModel, the do the post
$.ajax({
        url: 'your url',
        data:JSON.stringify(orderModel),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',//this is important!!
        success : function(msg) {
            //blah..
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //blah...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the following [tutorial](http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.fr/2010/05/aspnet-mvc-and-jquery-part-4-advanced.html]), which I found in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203912/asp-net-mvc-ajax-json-post-array) to write this answer. While this code hasn't been tested, hopefully it should put you on track. Please don't hesitate to ask if you have further questions.

After having populated your `orderModel` array in javascript, all you've left is posting that data with jquery. The jquery object contains an `ajax` method ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) which let you do that conveniently. The code below, placed at the end of your javascript code should do the trick:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    data: { models: orderModel }
});
```

Note that this ajax call will be performed on the URL of the displayed page. To choose a different URL, use the following code:

```
$.ajax(URL, { /* same data as above */ });
```

On the server side, as per the tutorial, you should have a class definition which holds a `models` property. That property will be filled in with the javascript array data you have collected in your script.

Merry Christmas!

Comment: Nope, I use other way to complete this.

Comment: ok, would you care writing your own answer to your question, so that others may benefit your experience?

Comment: This actually had the right idea, here's the complete answer though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499785/how-to-send-a-collection-array-to-mvc-action-via-ajax